# Multiple Image resize with same aspect ratio

Tags: php, javascript, image, resize, image-resizing

How can I resize multiple image with same aspect ratio. For example,

960x600
1152x720
1280x800
1440x900
1680x1050
1920x1200
2560x1600
2880x1800
3840x2400

these pixels are in same aspect ratio, if we have the image size 3840x2400. I need to resize the images from 3840x2400 into the above pixels. Preferably solved using either tool or PHP Script or Javascript.

Comment: Have you done any basic research?  Google'ed for PHP image resizing libraries?  Tried any code samples you found?

Answer (score 1):

```
<?php
  $source = imagecreatefromjpeg("path_to_source/filename.jpg");
  $width = 960;
  $height = $width*(imagesy($source)/imagesx($source));
  $destination = imagecreatetruecolor($width, $height);
  imagecopyresampled($destination, $source, 0, 0, 0, 0, $width, $height, imagesx($source), imagesy($source));
  imagejpeg($destination,"path_to_destination/filename.jpg");
?>
```

Alter `$width` for other sizes...